# Check that date is not in the past, client and server side

Tags: javascript, date, client-side, server-side

I have a **string** in this format: `2016-11-30`. I want to send this **string** from a **browser to a node server**.

Problem: I need to make sure that it's not in the past. It looks easy and answered a million times, **but** it needs to be:

- **Localized client-side**. If I am in Perth, the browser needs to complain if a date is in the past relative to the browser's time (GMT+8)
- **Localized server-side** -- relative to the client. The server doesn't know what timezone the client is in, but needs to complain if the date is in the past in the client's perspective. I can get the client to send a `Date string` over so that I can at least understand what timezone the client is in

Am I over-thinking this? Or is this as messy as it looks?

Answer (score 0):

Standardize it all to GMT format before every use.